# Trouble calling Azure Purview Rest API to update entity using Unique Attributes

Tags: azure-purview

I am trying to update an Entity's description in Purview using the "/atlas/v2/entity/uniqueAttribute/type/{typename}" endpoint and not able to make it work.

Rest API endpoint - https://XXXX.catalog.purview.azure.com/api/atlas/v2/entity/uniqueAttribute/type/azure_datalake_gen2_filesystem?attr:qualifiedName=https://XXXXXX.dfs.core.windows.net/testcont
Operation - PUT
Body  - {"description" : "test"}

Response -
{"requestId": "XXXX",    "errorCode": "RequestInvalid", "errorMessage": "Request is not recognized. Please verify the HTTP method, header or URL"}

Can someone please let me know what I am doing wrong here.